# Setting startup parameters for cluster-autoscaler in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, autoscaling

I have a kubernetes cluster running in AWS EKS, with the cluster-autoscaler [1] installed (using the helm provider for terraform [2]).

The cluster-autoscaler docs list a number of supported startup parameters[3], but it's not clear to me how to set them: can anybody point me in the right direction?

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

[3] https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-are-the-parameters-to-ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are deploying `cluster-autoscaler` with `terraform` `helm` provider you need to set additional parameters like you will do with `helm chart`.

All parameters are passed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/charts/cluster-autoscaler/values.yaml#L166).

Some example:

```
resource "helm_release" "autoscaler" {
  name       = "cluster-autoscaler"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler"
  chart      = "cluster-autoscaler"

  values = [
    "${file("values.yaml")}"
  ]

  set {
    name  = "extraArgs.leader-elect"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "extraArgs.scale-down-utilization-threshold"
    value = "0.8"
  }
}
```

As a bonus I would advise to move to [Karpenter](https://karpenter.sh/) since it is much better option if you are on `AWS`.